# Does Mpi Scatter send data in any kind of order

Tags: mpi

I saw this on internet

> MPI_Scatter takes an array of elements and distributes the elements in the order of process rank.

But I could not find it on the documentation.

I have an array and there are 4 processes. One process is root -> will scatter data among other 3 processes. The id-s are 0, 1, 2, 3.

Question: Will `MPI_Scatter()` or `MPI_Scatterv()` send the data in order, guaranteed?

Example 1:

```
0: [a, b, c, d, e]

// after scatter

1: [a, b]
2: [c, d]
3: [e]
```

Example 2:

```
0: [a, b]

// after scatter

1: [a]
2: [b]
3: [ ]
```

Also, does gather do the same thing? (preserve order)

Comment: `MPI_Scatter()` scatter the data to **all** tasks including itself. In your case, you need the `MPI_Scatterv()` variant since the send buffer size is not a multiple of the communicator size.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for the info. But still, will `MPI_Scatterv()` send data in order of proc rank?

Comment: @donjoe - with scatterv, the order is under your control.

Comment: @JonathanDursi And, since I have to control the order, do you think it's more efficient to use `scatterv` or manual `send / recv` ? (for similar examples to my question)

Comment: Scatterv will normally be more efficient since the implementation can use more efficient algorithms than a linear loop of sends.

Comment: Have you at least read the semantic of `MPI_Scatter()` ? If not, what is your expectation ? reverse order ? random order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The order is guaranteed according to the rank in the MPI_Comm.**

Below statement is copy pasted from open-mpi v2.1 documentation:

> An alternative description is that the root sends a message with
>   MPI_Send(sendbuf, sendcount * n, sendtype, ...). This message is split
>   into n equal segments, the ith segment is sent to the ith process in
>   the group, and each process receives this message as above. The send
>   buffer is ignored for all nonroot processes.